# Error While Adding Play Script To The Play Button In Unity 5.4

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am having some trouble while adding a load next level script to the play button.
Play Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1); //loads level 1

    }

}
```

I attached the above script to the Play button UI but when i click the button the level does not open! What's the error here? Confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `OnMouseDown()` is only called for old style GUI (IGUI) elements and GameObjects with colliders attached. ([see the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html))

What you need for this is to move your scene loading logic to another function, e.g. `void LoadLevel()`. Then you set up the UI button using the inspector to call that function.

**1:** Add a function to OnClick

Locate the Button component on your Play button object and click the plus at the bottom of the OnClick () area.

[image: OnClick for a Button in the Unity inspector]

**2:** Drag over the GameObject which has the script you'd like to run a function from.

In this case, I've just attached the script to the button itself. You should drop it on the left-hand box. Alternatively, you can click the circle to select the target GameObject from a list.

[image: Assigning a target GameObject to the OnClick list]

**3:** Use the dropdown to select the function

The dropdown will show you all scripts / components attached to the GameObject, then if you hover over one of those the available public functions on that script / component.

[image: Picking the function to run from the dropdown]